# How to use reflection to get a default constructor?

Tags: .net, reflection, constructor, default, abstract

I am writing a library that generates derived classes of abstract classes dynamically at runtime. The constructor of the derived class needs a `MethodInfo` of the base class constructor so that it can invoke it. However, for some reason `Type.GetConstructor()` returns `null`. For example:

```
abstract class Test
{
    public abstract void F();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(Test).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public, 
        null, System.Type.EmptyTypes, null); // returns null!
}
```

Note that `GetConstructor` returns `null` even if I explicitly declare a constructor in `Test`, and even if Test is not abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot the `BindingFlags.Instance` flag.

The strange thing is that

```
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(Test).GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
```

returns null. Is it defective?